# useEffect has a setState in it and is console.logging null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, use-effect, use-state

I will try to word this in the best way I can...

When I send a function through a prop to a child and then send it again to another child, then use the on click to activate it in the 'grandparent' function. When I console.log in that original function in the grandparent that console.logs a state, it prints undefined, yet when I am within that grandparent and try to activate that function, it will log the state correctly. If anyone can help me a little bit more in depth that would be great, we can call!

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

import Row from '../row/row';

import './body.css';

import { nanoid } from 'nanoid';

export default function Body () {
    
    const [boxMain, setBoxMain] = React.useState(null)

    const [rows, setRows] = React.useState(null)

    const ref = React.useRef(null)

    function changeBox (event) {
        console.log(event);
        console.log(boxMain);
    }

    React.useEffect(() => {

        /* Describes array with all information */
        const sideBoxes = 40; 
        
        const heightContainer = ref.current.offsetHeight
        const widthContainer = ref.current.offsetWidth;

        const numRows = Math.floor(heightContainer / sideBoxes) - 1
        const numBoxes = Math.floor(widthContainer / sideBoxes)

        /* Beginning of array birth */

        let main = Array(numRows).fill().map(() => new Array(numBoxes).fill({
            id: "",
            water: false,
            land: false,
            air: false,
        }));
        /* End of array birth */
        
        const rows = []
        for (let i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
            const id = nanoid();
            rows.push(
                <Row
                key={id}
                id={id}
                rowNumber={i}
                numBoxes={numBoxes}
                sideBoxes={sideBoxes}
                changeBox={changeBox}
                main={main}
                />
                )
            }

            setRows(rows)
            setBoxMain(main)

        }, [])

    
    return (
        <div>
            <div onClick={() => changeBox("test")}>
                TEST
            </div>
            <div ref={ref} className='body'>
                {rows}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

For examples here `onClick={() => changeBox("test")` the function works and logs "boxMain" correctly. But when I pass `changeBox={changeBox}` into ...

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";

import Box from "../box/box";

import "./row.css";

import { nanoid } from 'nanoid';

export default function Row (props) {
    
    const ref = React.useRef(null)
    const [boxes, setBoxes] = React.useState()

    useEffect(() => {
        
        const tempBoxes = []

        for (let i = 0; i < props.numBoxes; i++) {

            const id = nanoid()
            
            tempBoxes.push(
                <Box 
                    rowNumber={props.rowNumber}
                    columnNumber={i}
                    key={id} 
                    id={id}
                    side={props.sideBoxes}
                    changeBox={props.changeBox}
                    main={props.main}
                />
            )
        }

        setBoxes(tempBoxes)

    }, [])
    
    
    return (
        <div ref={ref} className="row-main">
            {boxes}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Then pass `changeBox={props.changeBox}` to ...

```
import React from "react";

import "./box.css";

export default function Box (props) {
    
    React.useEffect(() => {
        props.main[props.rowNumber][props.columnNumber] = props.id
    }, [])

    const [detectChange, setDetectChange] = React.useState(0)
    const ref = React.useRef(null)
    const styles = {
            width: `${props.side}px`,
            height: `${props.side}px`,
        }


    return (
        <div
            ref={ref}
            className="box-main"
            key={props.id}
            id={props.id}
            rownumber={props.rowNumber}
            columnnumber={props.columnNumber}
            style={styles}
            onClick={() => props.changeBox([props.id, props.rowNumber, props.columnNumber])}
        >
            
        </div>
    )
}
```

I then have the `onClick={() => props.changeBox([props.id, props.rowNumber, props.columnNumber])}` and it returns to the original changeBox...

```
 function changeBox (event) {
        console.log(event);
        console.log(boxMain);
    }
```

but when I click the box it returns the event correctly but returns boxMain as null.
When I click the onClick in the parent function although it console.logs everything correctly.

I know this is a ton of info but I know the fix has to be simple, or at least my method to do this should change.

Thank you for any feedback!! :)

Edit 1:

This is the output normally.

[image]

But when I simply add a space to the code and save it in VS Code (I guess some type of rerendering happens?) then it fixes to...

[image]

Although the IDs do change so I think everything refreshes in some way.

Comment: could you please add a jsfiddle or something where this can be reproduced?

Comment: Pretty sure I've read somewhere that storing JSX elements in state is not a good idea. See https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/issues/1248 and https://www.reddit.com/r/react/comments/s7uy58/how_bad_is_it_to_store_jsx_in_state/

Comment: I'm not sure why but if I put the call to `setRows(rows)` after the call to `setMain(main)` in the useEffect, the array for `mainBox` logs out ok from a click on `<Box/>`.

Comment: jsfiddle kept having issues :(

I read that too but I just want to render it once onto the page at the start. How could I do that without useEffect?

Comment: @arfi720, it works fine for me only when I go to my VS Code and save it. Then it pops out as it should, but when I refresh the page it goes back to its original state until I resave it by making a change (Just a space will do).

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. I am having the same effect - tricked me into thinking I had it working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `useEffect` hook of `Body` component runs only once because it does not have any dependency, thus `changeBox` callback passed to its children and grand children has the default state of `boxMain`, and it never updates.

This is why calling `changeBox` inside `Body` component logs `boxMain` array correctly, while calling `props.changeBox` inside children components logs `null`.

-------------- Solution ---------------------

This is not the BEST solution, but it will give you an idea why it didn't work before, and how you can fix it.

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

import Row from '../row/row';

import './body.css';

import { nanoid } from 'nanoid';

export default function Body () {

const [boxMain, setBoxMain] = React.useState(null)

const [rows, setRows] = React.useState(null)
const [rowsData, setRowsData] = React.useState(null)

const ref = React.useRef(null)

function changeBox (event) {
    console.log(event);
    console.log(boxMain);
}

React.useEffect(() => {

    /* Describes array with all information */
    const sideBoxes = 40; 
    
    const heightContainer = ref.current.offsetHeight
    const widthContainer = ref.current.offsetWidth;

    const numRows = Math.floor(heightContainer / sideBoxes) - 1
    const numBoxes = Math.floor(widthContainer / sideBoxes)

    /* Beginning of array birth */

    let main = Array(numRows).fill().map(() => new Array(numBoxes).fill({
        id: "",
        water: false,
        land: false,
        air: false,
    }));
    /* End of array birth */
    
    const rowsData = []
    for (let i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
        const id = nanoid();
        rowsData.push({
            key: id,
            id,
            rowNumber: id,
            numBoxes,
            sideBoxes,
        })
    }

    setRowsData(rowsData)
    setBoxMain(main)

}, [])

React.useEffect(() => {
    const rows = []
    for (let i = 0; i < rowsData?.length; i++) {
        const id = nanoid();
        const data = rowsData[i];
        rows.push(
            <Row
                {...data}
                changeBox={changeBox}
                main={boxMain}
            />
        )
    }
    setRows(rows)
}, [rowsData, boxMain, changeBox])


return (
    <div>
        <div onClick={() => changeBox("test")}>
            TEST
        </div>
        <div ref={ref} className='body'>
            {rows}
        </div>
    </div>
)
```

}

Comment: Thank you so much! I have been messing around with my stuff for the past few hours and restructured it with two React.useEffect and it's working perfectly! :)